# Calculate an integral using differentiating under the integral sign (Feynman's Trick)

Tags: calculus, integration

> Calculate $$\int_{0}^{441}{\frac{\pi\sin(\pi \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}}{dx}.$$

**My approach:** I know that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int{\frac{\pi\sin(\pi \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}}dx&=&\pi \int \frac{\sin(\pi\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\\
&=&2\int \sin(u)du,\quad u=\pi \sqrt{x}\\
&=&-2\cos(u)+C\\
&=&-2\cos(\pi \sqrt{x})+C
\end{eqnarray*}
so $$\int_{0}^{441}{\frac{\pi\sin(\pi \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}}{dx}.=4$$
but, how can solve this problem using **differentiating under the integral sign**?

Comment: Generally methods using Feynmans trick only work with definite integrals due to the fact you need to generate boundary conditions

Comment: I guess you could let $I(a) = \int_0^{441} a \frac{\pi \sin(\pi \sqrt x)}{\sqrt x} dx$ and then evaluate $I’(a)$ the exact same way, just for the sake of using Feynman’s technique.

Comment: @HenryLee You're right. I edited my post.

Comment: @Tavish I'm just getting started with the method, maybe you could enlighten me with an answer on your suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @АлександрПальма I don’t know, though. It’s a really cheeky way of doing it.

Comment: @Tavish I don't understand your comment. However, thank you so much. I will continue to use your hint.

Comment: @АлександрПальма Sure, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Tavish Using your hint, we can see that $I'(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{441}\frac{\pi\sin(\pi \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ but it's the same that in my solution.

Comment: @АлександрПальма Yes, that’s why I said this method was cheeky. It still uses differentiation under the integral sign, though.

Comment: @Александр *If* an answer was helpful to you, please don't forget to 'accept' it, so this question is marked as resolved.

Comment: @Sal Yes, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$ I(a)=\int_0^c dx\ \frac{\sin(ax^{1/2})}{x^{1/2}}$$

We've chosen $a$ so that taking the derivative will simplify$^\dagger$ the expression.

$$ \partial_aI(a)=\int_0^c dx \ \cos(ax^{1/2})$$

Now we perform the $x$ integral

$$ \partial_aI(a)= \frac{2}{a^2} \left( a c^{1/2} \sin(ac^{1/2})+\cos(ac^{1/2})-1 \right) $$

Then the $a$ integral

$$ I(a)=\frac{2}{a} \left( 1- \cos(ac^{1/2})\right) +C$$

To find $C$ note that $I(0)=0$ from the first equation. In this case $C=0$ and we have

$$ I(a)=\frac{2}{a} \left( 1- \cos(ac^{1/2})\right)$$

Setting $a=\pi, c=441$, and multiplying by $\pi$ gives exactly $4$.

$\dagger$ In this case, it's not clear if the 'simplified' integral is actually simpler to do on paper. Still, this is the general idea behind Feynman's trick.